# Issues with when writing to database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm unable to write to my database while using this script that I whipped up earlier.

```php
<?php
include("db.php");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    // Data sent from form, then posted to  "admin" table in database
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
    $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']); 
    $author = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
    $image = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['image']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO admin(name,description,author,image,category) VALUES('$name','$description','$author','$image','$category');";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    header("Location: video.php?file=' . $filename . '");
}
?>
```

And here's my SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE admin
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
    description VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
    author VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
    image VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
    category VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE 
);
```

Everything is submitted with POST via an HTML form. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, so that why I'm wondering what you guys think. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you even sure that you get inside your if condition?

Comment: None. I check my table after the header redirects, and nothing is posted

Comment: Can you `var_dump($result)`? You may want to add `if (!$results) { die(mysql_error()); }` to see if there is a mysql error.

Comment: Guys, not really sure. Everything seems to be working fine. It can't be MYSQL, it must be on my end via the PHP.

Comment: `$author` is misspelled as `$auhtor`; does fixing that make a difference? Also, your `Location:` header's quotes are mixed up.

Comment: @minitech nope, that didn't do the trick. Also the quotes have to be that way. I have another snippet of code that renders out a file after the header is loaded.

Comment: @digital-precision I didn't get an error, but my HTML disappeared after I added that piece of code to the snippet.

Comment: @Pxlc: No, look at the syntax highlighting. You need single quotes on either end, not double quotes. Right now you're mixing the two. That's not a valid URL. Also, try adding this at the top: `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` and see if anything gets output.

Comment: @minitech That's telling me there is an error on line 13. I also removed the header to see if that might be causing anything to malfunction.

Comment: @Pxlc :D What *kind* of error?

Comment: @minitech  Notice: Undefined variable: author in /home/a4208795/public_html/info.php on line 13

Comment: @Pxlc: Okay, make the `$auhtor` -> `$author` fix then.

Comment: @Pxlc: Chances are the html disappeared b/c the header didn't get called due to die. You can do a `var_dump(mysql_error()); exit;`

Comment: @minitech Wow, that actually worked. I'm able to see data in the table. Except numbers, they don't seem to be posting to the table

Comment: @Pxlc: Numbers shouldn't be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`$result = mysql_query($sql)` is not valid (no connection specified).

It needs to be `$result = mysql_query($sql, [CONNECTION])`;

There may be other issues, but that's an obvious one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the db is specified in `db.php` I don't think you need to explicitly mention a connection if there's only one.

Comment: What would the connection be, my db?

Comment: Unless he opens the connection in his `db.php` file, in which case the last link opened with `mysql_connect()` will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open a MySQL connection (if not omitted in the snippet)
2. Check your MySQL statement by using `var_dump($sql)`
3. Check for the return value of `mysql_query()`, should be `true` if the INSERT statement succeeded.
4. Check for the number of rows affected by the INSERT statement: `mysql_affected_rows()`

Note:
I'm pretty sure that your INSERT statement fails because **all your columns are defined as UNIQUE**. As soon as you already have an author with the same name the statement fails!

Answer (score -1):

```
$auhtor=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
```

The Author variable is spelled wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't that just cause the `author` column to be filled with the empty string?

Comment: Fixed, still the same. Nothing added.

Comment: It wouldn't cause no data to be inserted into his database though.